# Is it more common/acceptable to use "francophonisms" for modern words or just the original English term?

Tags: choix-de-mot, noms, néologismes, informatique

I've noticed that for modern words, particularly those related to technology, the original English words and the corresponding French words are both often used in French writing. For example, I might find “*courriel*” used instead of “*e-mail*”, or "*CD-ROM*" used instead of “*cédérom*”.

Which of these is more common or acceptable to use? Is there a distinction between casual and formal use?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

La réponse est très différente suivant les pays.

La France a tendance à être chauviniste et statique. Lorsqu'un concept nouveau apparaît, il commence par y avoir de la résistance à l'adoption d'un mot nouveau, qu'il soit ou non d'origine anglaise. Forcément le terme anglais commence à être utilisé. Ensuite, une francisation officielle ou un terme dérivé indépendamment apparaît, mais il est peu adopté. Exemple : tout le monde écrit « CD-ROM » et prononce « cédérome ». Pour le courriel, le terme a pris un peu, mais « email » (prononcé « imeyle », « imèle », « émail » ou quelques autres variantes) ou « mail » (prononcé « meyle », « mail » ou autres variantes) se disent et s'écrivent souvent. Par exemple, sur le site du [Monde](http://www.lemonde.fr/), on trouve quelques « [cederom](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22cederom%22+lemonde.fr) » mais beaucoup plus de « [CD-ROM](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22cd-rom%22+lemonde.fr) » ; il y a surtout des « [email](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22email%22+lemonde.fr) » et des « [e-mail](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22e-mail%22+lemonde.fr) » mais aussi quelques « [courriel](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22courriel%22+lemonde.fr) ».

Le Québec a tendance à beaucoup plus vite franciser un terme anglais, tantôt en adoptant le mot, tantôt en imitant la structure. « Courriel » en vient d'ailleurs.

Comment: Je pense qu'il est plus souhaitable de répondre en anglais aux questions posées en anglais, et en français aux questions posées en français (bien qu'il semble que ta réponse convienne au demandeur).

Comment: @Raphink Je préfère que le site soit [avant tout francophone](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/2/quelle-est-la-langue-principale-du-site-what-is-the-primary-language-of-the-site/30#30) et dans le [débat](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/q/14) je soutiens plutôt la [position de Stéphane](http://meta.french.stackexchange.com/questions/14/answering-in-the-other-language/36#36).

Comment: Je cite : "La France a tendance à être chauviniste et statique." C'est visible par exemple quand dans un site bilingue les francophones militent pour donner la priorité au français. Un combat d'arrière garde selon moi. Je rappelle qu'au moins le tiers des mots anglais sont d'origine française avec un autre tiers d'origine latine. Le français quant à lui est loin en effet de montrer autant d'ouverture.

Comment: @Raphink Encore faut-il être capable de faire un thème sans faute, ni contre-sens. Sans aucun chauvinisme, et par respect des éventuels lecteurs, je rédige dans la langue que je maîtrise. Hors de toutes les chapelles, la France est une république laï qui s'amuse de Clochemerle et des certitudes des Cafés du Commerce Académique. Victor Hugo n'était-il pas réticent à parler l'anglais? pourtant était-il un homme fermé? Sans compter que l'anglais n'est pas la langue maternelle de tous les lecteurs, et qu'il recherchent sur ce site l'intelligibilité et les usages d'une langue.

Comment: ... suite : Corriger "république laïque" - Sachant que la version est plus facile que le thème il est tout à fait normal que les lecteurs qui maîtrisent mieux l'anglais que le français utilisent celle-là, ... en toute liberté.

Answer (score 11):

It depends on the target audience and its country.

I noticed that France's French press use French version of words more often than in Belgium or Switzerland.

However in Canada (Quebec), French is so protected that using English version of word is sometimes prohibited. A business partner explained me that he wasn't able to use English words in his commercial publications, including his company name!

I personnaly don't care as long as the information can be received by a maximum number of people.

The situation is confusing only for a very limited numbers of words (e.g.: un portable is a phone in France and a PC in Switzerland), for which native speakers are well aware. They will correct almost automatically without even noticing.

Answer (score 7):

"Formal use" in *France* (not necessarily French-speaking countries) has a very specific tie to the Académie Française and its recommendations (as well as a few other institutionalised references for grammar, syntax etc. such as Grevisse).

As such, if you want to be in full conformity with the official French standard of French (and people who write in newspapers or textbooks usually want to), you follow the recommendations of the Académie, which has historically (over the past few decades, at least) gone with the strange habit of forcefully "frenchifying" the spelling of English neologisms, resulting in abhorrent (imho) French neologisms such as "mêl".

As pointed above, other countries (OK: mostly Québec) with a vested interest in preserving the perceived purity of their practice of French have adopted different localisation strategies, such as translating the concept, rather than the transliterating the word (e.g. "couriel" for "mail" instead of Franco-French "mêl", which makes considerably more sense, at least).

At the end of the day, this falls down to the usual prescriptivism vs. descriptivism debate. And while the norm in France leans firmly toward the former (*Académie Française oblige*), many educated people will step in to defend the latter approach as well.

The examples you give are technical, computer-related, words (which typically make the bulk of neologisms these days) and I think there is a strong professional bias amongst IT/computer-proficient people in France toward using unmodified English spelling, perhaps having to do with a higher English proficiency. In such circles (including in corporate contexts), using a spelling like "cédérom" instead of "CD-ROM" would make you sound somewhat "dated" or computer-illiterate, rather than formal (OK, using the *word* CD-ROM probably will do that anyway, but that's another issue entirely...).

Comment: Québec isn't a country.  Yet.  :-P

Comment: @Jez: I realised that when writing, but "Canada's Québec" had a rather unnatural ring to it, and would have been no less likely to start a controversy :-P

Comment: Where's the +10 button? :) I *strongly* believe that francophones are repeatedly handicapped by their own prescriptivism. Geopolitical history (and navies) aside, I think that if the English language is 'winning' (as we so often hear bemoaned), it's because there is no taboo about 'playing' with the language and new words, and no qualms about pinching words from other languages if they "work".

Comment: @Benjol: that's for an entire other debate, but yes: I agree that, all geopolitics aside, French practically ensured its limited expansion by setting strict bounds to its flexibility, at a time when English gleefully kept evolving and mutating (often toward more streamlined practices) to accommodate contemporary realities...

Answer (score 3):

As for which is more common, it depends on the specific pair of words. For example, I don't think native French words for "chewing-gum" and "shampooing" even exist. On the other hand, "ordinateur portable" is much more common than "laptop", which is also used.

My guess is that there are more Anglicisms in more casual registers, but I don't know to what extent.

There is, however, a difference depending on different national varieties of French. French Canadians are much more likely to say "courriel" than the people of France, for example. Then again, French Canadians have their own set of anglicisms, of course.

Finally, as for which is more "acceptable", I think this is totally subjective (maybe even meaningless!) and not really the type of question that I think it makes sense to discuss on this site.

Comment: where I you from? Stationnement is actually widely used here (Belgium). Shampooing is the French translation of Shampoo.

Comment: I'm not from a French-speaking country. I don't believe "stationnement" is common in France, but since I'm not Francophone I'm certainly not an authority on the subject.

Comment: I had lived in lot of different places in France and "stationnement" is also widely used in most of them.

Comment: I'll bow to your experience then and remove that example from my post :)

Comment: @Brennan Vincent: my guess is that parking is more used in Belgium than in France, and more used that Stationnement. But stationnement is widely used in all administrative stuff (written french).

Comment: Speaking as a French francophone: *stationnement* and *parking* have different meanings. Le *stationnement* is the action of parking a car; *une aire de stationnement* is a place where you can park a car. A *parking* is a building or a zone that is usually separated from the street, where you can park. *Shampooing* is fully accepted in French since the 19th century and has no exact alternative. *Chewing-gum* has been in sporadic use since the 19th century as well, though the word only became common after WW2, and I've heard « gomme à mâcher ».

Comment: En Belgique, on utilise parfois "chique". Sauf dans la région de Liège, où "chique" veut dire "bonbon" (et "bonbon" "biscuit").

Comment: En Suisse (et apparemment aussi [en Belgique](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/chiclette)), on dit parfois 'chiclette'.

Answer (score 1):

As the others said, it's very region-dependent.

In the specific case of Belgium, we tend to use the English words more easily and find the forced French versions a bit silly (“*butineur*” for browser, “*bolidage*” for tuning,…) and that's when we even know them. The main reason for that is because we have to co-exist with Dutch speakers, and dutch adopts foreign words much more easily (albeit in a strange fashion sometimes).

---

Comme les autres l'ont dit, cela dépend fort des régions.

Dans le cas de la Belgique, les Belges ont tendance à utiliser plus facilement les mots anglais et à trouver les versions francisées un peu bizarres (Sérieusement, un « butineur »??). La principale raison est l'influence des néerlandophones, vu que le néerlandais intègre plus facilement des mots d'origine étrangère.

Comment: Les Français aussi trouvent le mot « butineur » bizarre, voire incompréhensible hors contexte (on écrit « navigateur » et on dit « navigateur » ou « brahouzeur/brozeur »).

Answer (score 0):

Je pense qu'il faille faire attention car des mots anglais se retrouvent dans certains dictionnaires français à tort. Par exemple, si je me souviens bien, le mot "ferry" se retrouve dans "Le Petit Robert", alors qu'un mot plus qu'adéquat existe, soit "traversier".

Aussi, ce n'est pas parce qu'un mot est utilisé qu'il est bon. Pour utiliser l'un de vos exemples, "cédérom" est probablement un des mots les plus aberrants qu'il puisse y avoir. Le bon mot est "disque compact", et on laisse tomber la partie "ROM" car il n'y a pas vraiment d'acronymes reconnus pour la "Read-only memory" (mémoire morte) en français.

Comment: Votre définition de "plus qu'adéquat" me laisse un peu songeur: "traversier" est un mot pratiquement inconnu hors du Québec. Le fait que "ferry" ait une origine anglophone (comme des milliers de mots plus anciens que personne ne songerait à bouter hors de France du fait de leur origine) n'en fait pas moins le terme standard en usage, et il a par conséquent tout à fait sa place dans un dictionnaire. Le fond de ce débat ne mènera pas à grand chose, il s'agit essentiellement de querelles d'Églises, dépendant des inclinations prescriptivistes/descriptivistes de chacun...

Comment: J'avais vu une interview d'une des personnes responsable du Robert qui expliquait qu'il ajoutait des mots dès qu'ils étaient utilisés massivement, comme par exemple "blog". Un de leurs critères était notamment le nombre de résultats retourné par une recherche sur Google.

Comment: @Louhike: je pense que, de ce point de vue, il y a eu un changement majeur de la politique des grands dictionnaires français (peut-être justement grâce à l'apparition de nouveaux outils comme l'Internet): le prescriptivisme d'il y a 30 ans (où le Robert se contentait de recopier, en étoffant, les communiqués de l'Académie) a fait place à une approche plus similaire à celle des dictionnaires anglo-saxons...