# What is the correct way to write "10 MB" in French?

Tags: abréviations, unités

A search at [linguee.fr](http://www.linguee.fr/francais-anglais/search?sourceoverride=none&source=auto&query=10%20MB) shows the following translations of MB (megabyte):

- 10 MO
- 10 Mo
- 10M
- 10MB

**What is the correct way to write "10 MB" in French?**

Answer (score 18, accepted):

L'unité en question est *[mégaoctet](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet)*, qui s'abrège en **Mo**. Il faut une [espace insécable](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_ins%C3%A9cable) entre le nombre et l'unité de mesure. Cette espace peut être, selon les règles de style suivies, de largeur normale ou [fine](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_typographique). Donc: **10 Mo**.

---

Noter de plus que l'utilisation de *MB* peut prêter à confusion avec le *[mégabit](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit)* (en anglais: *megabit*), qui est huit fois plus petit (1 octet = 8 bits), et qui a pour unité *Mb* (en anglais: *Mbit*).

Comment: The corresponding [binary unit](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Binary_prefix) is the *mébioctet* (Mio) which is 1 048 576 bytes.

Comment: Excellente réponse, néanmoins je ne crois pas que *mégabit* se traduise en anglais par *megabyte*. En anglais, un *byte* est bien un octet. Et l'abréviation MB signifie bien *megabyte*.

Comment: @Lierre Non, ça ne se traduit pas comme ça, mais on peut confondre le symbole des deux unités puisque seule la casse diffère.

Comment: @Lierre merci de cette remarque, j'ai corrigé ma réponse

Comment: Notons également que les termes « byte » et « octet » existent tous les deux en anglais et en français, et ne représentent pas le même concept (même si au final, ça désigne souvent la même chose). Un octet égal huit bits, alors qu'un byte est la plus petite unité adressable par le processeur (ce qui, sur la grande majorité des machines, est également 8 bits). Les anglophones ont simplement pris l'habitude de dire « byte », et les francophones « octet ».

Answer (score 4):

In theory, *Mo* would be correct (for mégaoctet), see [the wikipedia article on Méga](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9ga)

I'm fairly sure however that a lot of people would use MB, depending again on whether they use "byte" or "octet" the most (see also [this question on the use of English terms in French](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10/is-it-more-common-acceptable-to-use-francophonisms-for-modern-words-or-just-the))

En théorie, *Mo* est l'abbréviation correcte. Voir [l'article wikipedia sur le préfixe Méga](http://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9ga)

Par contre, je pense que pas mal de gens utilisent MB, suivant qu'ils utilisent plutôt "byte" ou "octet" (Voir aussi [cette question sur l'utilisation de termes anglais en français](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/10/is-it-more-common-acceptable-to-use-francophonisms-for-modern-words-or-just-the))

Comment: J'ai très rarement vu des francophones utiliser "MB". À l'oral, on parle de "méga" ou de "Mo" [emo], jamais de "MB" [embé].

Comment: Je pensais que la question portait plutôt sur l'écrit et j'ai répondu en ce sens. Mais bonne remarque, l'oral est différent. En Belgique, j'entends en général "méga" (parfois "mégabyte" en entier), mais jamais Mb [emb] ni Mo [emo].