# Emploie-t-on aujourd'hui le terme courriel ou mél à la place de e-mail ?

Tags: usage, néologismes, informatique

Je suis sous l'impression visiblement fausse qu'employer des termes comme *mél* ou *courriel* est dépassé et qu'aujourd'hui tout le monde utilise l'anglicisme *e-mail*.

Selon mon analyse, j'ai eu plus l'impression que des personnes totalement étrangères à l'outil informatique utilisent soit *courriel* ou *mél*, alors que *e-mail* semble plus populaire chez les initiés.

J'utilise pour ma part exclusivement *e-mail*, mais de temps en temps j'entends les autres termes revenir (rarement il faut avouer).

Est-il toujours selon vous courant de parler de *courriel* ou *mél*, ou bien est-ce totalement dépassé ? Avez-vous des pistes sur pourquoi ces deux termes ont été très majoritairement abandonnés au profit d'un anglicisme qui a pourtant moins de sens pour les Français ? Existe-t-il une différence fondamentale entre *courriel* et *mél*, des situations dans lesquelles on emploierait l'un et pas l'autre ?

Comment: Francophone de France je n'utilise que courriel autant par oral que par écrit et tout le monde me comprend et j'ai l'impression (qu'à mon contact ?) de plus en plus de mes correspondants l'utilisent. Je me garderais bien d'employer e-mail !

Comment: Question similaire: http://french.stackexchange.com/q/10/79

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- « [mél.](http://www.culture.gouv.fr/culture/dglf/mel.htm) » n'a jamais été proposé comme mot, mais comme une abréviation à employer pour signaler une adresse en parallèle avec « tél. » introduisant un numéro de téléphone; ce document propose des termes à employer plutôt qu' « email ». On remarquera que « courriel » est absent des propositions qui ne comportent que des locutions, tout en permettant de distinguer le message, l'adresse et le système.
- « courriel » est à ma connaissance d'origine canadienne et n'a jamais pris en France, du moins dans mon entourage, qu'il soit *initié* ou non. Je l'utilise quand je cherche explicitement à éviter les anglicismes, mais « email » fait partie des anglicismes que j'ai dans mon vocabulaire de tous les jours.

Comment: *Courriel* n'a jamais vraiment pris, mais j'ai le sentiment que son faible usage ne faiblit pas d'avantage. Le mot est plutôt joli, je pense qu'il continuera de perdurer.

Comment: Oui, *courriel* est effectivement d'origine canadienne et il est très utilisé ici. Jamais *mél* ou *mail* n'est utilisé, et *e-mail* ne s'utilise que dans des situations informelles.

Comment: Quand je vois écrit *e-mail* sans tiret j'ai tendance à lire *émail* c'est assez perturbant.

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez, c'est tellement l'usage dans mon entourage (anglophone et francophone) que je n'avais jamais fait le rapprochement. Il faut dire que, bien que je fréquente un médecin et des amoureux de la langue, je ne connais personne qui s'occupe d'émaux.

Comment: Il faudrait plutôt [ce lien](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/terme/INFO650?from=list&francetermeSearchTerme=m%C3%A9l.&francetermeSearchDomaine=0) je crois. Merci !

Answer (score 5):

[L'administration française](http://www.budget.gouv.fr/mentions-legales) demande d'envoyer un ***courriel*** au webmaster, c'est  l'usage en francophonie ; l'encadrement parle de *courriel* lorsqu'il envoie des messages en internes.

Il m'est arrivé d'utiliser *mél* lorsque cette traduction a été proposée (aux temps préhistoriques de l'informatique).

Pour une correspondance officielle *courriel* signe une francophonie affichée, surtout quand la syntaxe est respectée et l'orthographe corrigée.

Souvent lu pour l'expédition en retour : *adresse électronique*.

Rarement utilisé à l'oral, on prononce *mél* en pensant *mail*

Il y a aussi une question d'âge, ceux "nés et élevés" avant le Web et dont certains enfants envoient des SMS qu'ils ne savent relire (anecdotique mais vérifié : "Qu'est-ce que tu as voulu me dire : ben ... j'sais plus.") utiliseront plutôt *courriel*.

Les entreprises sont parfois obligées de donner des cours d'orthographe et de rédaction (sous des noms beaucoup plus flatteur de "Maîtrise du discours public", "Plan Qualité de la correspondance" ...) aux jeunes diplômés ; avoir un C.V. avec *courriel* et une bonne orthographe peut ouvrir les portes de la promotion.

Comment: Enfin, on prononce mél en francisant le mot mail.

Answer (score 5):

**English reader version :**
I support [oldergod's answer](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2468/9495) mainly, but I just wanted to add a remark about the usage of the word in oral language.

It must be said that here in France we hear a lot the very controversial *mail* (not *mél*; I must make it precise because of the slightly different sounding. *mél* -> [mel], but *mail* -> [meijl]). That, however, doesn't satisfy neither the people defending against too much anglicisms nor fluent English speakers who foresee a possible confusion with actual *mail*, i.e. "snailmail". This observation on pronunciation doesn't in fact legitimate the usage I describe, but it must be taken in account that it's quite heavily used in oral context.

**Version française :**
Je m'associe principalement à la [réponse d'oldergod](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/2468/9495) qui me semble juste, mais je voulais simplement ajouter une remarque concernant l'usage du terme dans la langue orale.

Il faut avouer qu'en France on entend énormément le très controversé *mail* (et non *mél*, je le souligne car la prononciation la plus répandue fait bien "sonner" le mot à l'anglaise [meijl]), compromis qui pourtant ne satisfait ni les personnes hostiles à l'introduction d'anglicismes ni les anglophones un tant soit peu expérimentés qui y voient l'introduction d'une confusion (improbable mais potentielle) avec le mot anglais à l'origine du composite *e-mail* (*mail* = courrier postal). Cela n'en rend pas l'usage légitime, mais il faut reconnaître que cette forme "dégradée" est très répandue à l'oral.

Comment: On dit très souvent *mail* pour un courriel en anglais, hein. Ce n'est pas un gallicisme.

Comment: @Gilles, je n'ai jamais entendu *mail* en anglais pour **un** courriel.  C'est un peu hors-sujet, mais aurais-tu une citation?

Comment: @Gilles, en anglais (au moins en Angleterre), *mail* n'est quasiment jamais utilisé pour *e-mail*. *Mail* sera compris dans le sens postal (*post* est aussi beaucoup utilisé). Comme Samuel le dit, c'est aussi un nom global (le courrier en général, pas *un* courrier).

Comment: @Bruno C'est pourtant courant, au moins aux US. On dit *[You've Got Mail](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You've_Got_Mail)*, pas “you've got email”. Et aussi “Re: your mail”, “Did you get my mail?”, “I received a mail”… Le mot *email* est plus courant que *mail* dans ce contexte, mais *mail* se dit aussi.

Comment: On peut écrire mail mais on entend les gens en France ou des français **dire** mél.

Answer (score 4):

**Courriel / Mél.**

D’origine québécoise, courriel, qui s’est répandu dans l’usage comme équivalent de l’anglais e-mail, désigne le message électronique et peut être, par extension, employé au sens de messagerie électronique : envoyer un courriel ; confirmer sa venue par téléphone ou par courriel.

Ce terme a été approuvé par l’Académie française en juin 2003. Toutefois les termes message électronique d’un côté et messagerie électronique de l’autre, peuvent être employés comme synonymes de courriel.

En revanche, on ne peut substituer mél. à courriel puisque mél. n’est pas un mot plein, mais l’abréviation de messagerie électronique. Il doit s’utiliser uniquement devant une adresse électronique, de même qu’on utilise tél. uniquement devant un numéro de téléphone. Mél. : untel@voila.fr

(Source : [Académie Française](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#26_strong-em-courriel-ml-em-strong))

A titre personnel, j'emplois plus fréquemment "email", entends régulièrement "courriel", n'ai jamais utilisé "mél.", mais connais sa signification.

Comment: Pareillement pour moi; j'emploie en général "courrier électronique" ou les emprunts "e-mail" ou "email". Je ne suis pas choqué par "courriel". Je trouve ridicule le "mél"

Comment: Mél n'est pas une abréviation. mél est une prononciation francisée du mot mail.

Answer (score 2):

Je n'ai jamais vu *mél* de ma vie. Parlerais-tu de *mail* ?

*Courriel* est utilisé majoritairement dans un contexte formel ou par certains amoureux de la langue française. Je ne pense pas que ce terme fut *abandonné* car il n'a jamais vraiment pris. J'emploierais *courriel* dans un email lié à une offre d'emploi par exemple.
J'utiliserais toutefois *email* dans un contexte moins formel comme je viens de le faire.

Les plus courants sont à mon avis, *mail* et *e-mail* ou *email*.

Comment: Non je parlais bien de __mél__, c'est peu courant mais definitivement employe, j'ai pense au debut a un accent  inhabituel, mais non il y a certaines (rares) personnes qui utilisent ce terme.

Answer (score 1):

L'utilisation de *mél* et *courriel* dépend largement des conventions utilisées dans le contexte où tu l'utilises.

Personnellement, j'ai essayé d'utiliser mél dans le contexte de mon entreprise, où beaucoup de mots en anglais sont utilisés à la place des mots français (*user* à la place d'*utilisateur*, etc.), ce qui a été vu d'un assez mauvais oeil.

Je pense que ces mots sont compris par les gens, mais ils peuvent passer pour du snobisme ou une tentative exotique de se démarquer du langage commun. Pourtant, quand on tente d'utiliser ces francisations, c'est souvent pour éviter la *novlangue corporate* et justement s'éloigner d'un certain snobisme.

Même observation pour *pourriel* (*spam*).