# Une redirection courriel, courielle ou autre?

Tags: orthographe, informatique, néologismes, france

Je cherche à éviter le franglais « mettre en place une redirection email ».

Dans cette phrase, « email » est un adjectif si je ne me trompe. Dans le cadre du courrier postal, on dirait « mettre en place une redirection postale ».

À l'oral, je dis « mettre en place une redirection courriel(le) ».

Ma question en contient deux en réalité:

- Est-ce que « redirection courriel(le) » est le terme exact en français de France ? ([J'ai cru comprendre que le terme est québecois d'origine, mais il a été accepté par l'académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/la-langue-francaise/questions-de-langue#26_strong-em-courriel-ml-em-strong))
- Comment dois-je l'écrire ? Ici « courriel » deviens un adjectif, n'est-ce pas? Est-ce qu'il se féminise en « courrielle » comme « postal » est devenu « postale » ?

Comment: La partie de la question portant sur l'usage de courriel [a déjà été posée ici](http://french.stackexchange.com/q/2467/358) et a déjà une réponse.

Comment: re: Qc voir [ici](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8353974).

Comment: @Laure Pour la première partie de la question, ma question était plus dans le sens « est-ce que je peux utiliser “redirection courriel(le)” » en français, vu que c'est un nom, puis-je l'utiliser comme adjectif ?

Comment: J'aurais dit "une redirection des courriels"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Courriel* est le terme reçu en France depuis la publication au Journal Officiel du 20/06/2003. Voir sur [France Terme](http://www.culture.fr/franceterme/result?francetermeSearchTerme=courriel&francetermeSearchDomaine=0&francetermeSearchSubmit=rechercher&action=search).
Il n'est pour l'instant officiellement préconisé de ne l'employer que comme un nom, car il a été calqué sur le mot courrier qui est uniquement utilisé que comme substantif.

Une recherche google donne quelques résultats sur [« redirection courriel »](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=redirection%20courriel&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=&gws_rd=ssl) et aucune sur [« redirection courrielle »](https://www.google.fr/search?as_q=&as_epq=redierction%20courrielle&as_oq=&as_eq=&as_nlo=&as_nhi=&lr=&cr=&as_qdr=all&as_sitesearch=&as_occt=any&safe=images&as_filetype=&as_rights=&gws_rd=ssl#as_qdr=all&q=%22redirection%20courrielle%22). De tous les dictionnaires consultés sur internet je n'ai trouvé que le wiktionnaire pour donner [courriel comme adjectif](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/courriel).
Mon correcteur orthographique surligne *courrielle* mais pas *courriel*.

J'en conclus que pour l'instant la majorité des emplois de « courriel » se fait en tant que nom commun bien que la logique grammaticale serait qu'il soit adjectif dans cette expression.  En fait « redirection courriel » avec *courriel* employé comme nom sonne comme une construction bancale à mes oreilles et j'aurais envie de dire « redirection de courriels ».

Ceci est certainement dû au fait que l'usage s'est d'abord imposé à l'oral et, qu'à l'oral, la prononciation est identique que l'on prononce *courriel* ou *courrielle*. Je parierais fort que l'usage, qui n'est pas encore tellement fixé, va évoluer et que « courriel » sera bientôt signalé partout aussi comme adjectif et donc que l'accord à l'écrit se fera aussi, ou pourra se faire.

Personnellement j'emploie le mot déjà en tant qu'adjectif et voir écrit « redirection courrielle » ne me gêne pas du tout, mais je suis du côté de ceux qui disent qu'une langue doit vivre et doit être faite par ceux qui la parlent. Il peut y avoir des gens qui disent que tant que ce n'a pas été validé par une parution au Journal Officiel mieux vaut s'en tenir à l'emploi du mot comme substantif et d'ici là écriront « redirection courriel ».

Comment: +1, bien entendu pour sa substance, mais aussi pour l'observation dans son paragraphe ultime. Moi, j’irais même plus loin car d'après moi les langues qui ne changent que rarement et lentement risquent de finir un jour sur "La Voie Sacrée" marchant vers l'oublie pour rejoindre le latin et les autres langues qui ne bougent plus du tout.

Answer (score 3):

Je réponds à ma propre question, bien que je sois pas l'auteur de la réponse en question. Curieux, j'ai demandé à l’Académie Française :

> Monsieur,
>
> Mettre en place une redirection n'est pas très heureux. *Redirection* ne figure dans aucun des dictionnaires que j'ai consultés. Ne serait-il pas possible de dire simplement *Rediriger le courrier* ?
>
> Cordialement,

J'ai répondu que « *rediriger les courriels* » marchait car je ne voulais pas entamer un débat.

J'ai accepté la réponse de Laure comme réponse valide, car j'ai bien aimé quand elle explique qu'une « *langue doit vivre et doit être faite par ceux qui la parlent.* » *Redirection* reste pour moi un mot valide et très courant.

Comment: *Rediriger les courriels* signifierait plutôt que vous rediriger *les courriers*, courriers qui peuvent venir sur leurs chevaux des multiples postes de votre royaume porteurs de plis cachetés. :)