# "Mail" convient-il pour "E-mail" ?

Tags: traduction, anglais, email

Devant traduire `Email` en français sur une application, le développeur précédent a utilisé `Mail` pourtant ce mot veut dire tout autre chose en anglais.

Je pense que beaucoup de français utilisent e-mail ou mail au lieu d'utiliser courriel, le but de l'application n'est pas non plus d'être dans le meilleur français possible mais d'être tournée vers ce qui s'utilise le plus, je trouve donc le mot courriel un peu vieillot et j'étais décidé à utiliser `E-mail` avant de tomber sur `Mail`.

Le mot `Mail` est vraiment juste en français ? Ou vaut-il mieux utiliser `E-mail`?

Answer (score 7):

*Vieillot* pour qualifier *courriel* me semble inapproprié. On peut très bien qualifier de vieillote une appelation qui a eu son heure de gloire et tend à disparaître pour une raison ou pour une autre, qu’un nouveau terme prenne le devant de la scène, abréviation (*ciné* ou *cinoche* pour *cinéma*, ce dernier pour *cinématographe*) ou nouvelle désignation (*galaxie* pour *univers-île*), ou que la réalité qu’elle décrit soit de moins en moins fréquente (on dit aujourd’hui plutôt *le dernier album* d’un artiste que *son dernier disque* ou *son dernier cd*, qui furent en leur temps des expressions communes).

*Courriel*, de son côté, est un néologisme créé au Québec, très communément utilisé au Québec, en très grande majorité par rapport à *e-mail* ou *mail*. Au vu de son omniprésence dans toutes les couches de la société et de son usage par les gens de toutes les générations, on ne le qualifierait sûrement pas, aujourd’hui encore, de vieillot.

Ailleurs dans la Francophonie, *e-mail* ou *mail* ont été utilisés d’emblée, et *courriel* y est apparu sous étiquette de [recommandation officielle](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/questions-de-langue#26_strong-em-courriel-ml-em-strong) par l’Académie française, et [imposé par l’administration française à ses employés](https://www.letemps.ch/no-section/banni-lacademie-francaise-email-seratil-supplante-un-jour-courriel).

De la même manière qu’un excellent roman est quasi par définition d’un ennui profond lorsque sa lecture est imposée par un professeur d’école, il me semble bien compréhensible qu’il existe un phénomène de rejet ou de résistance face à un mot imposé à toute une société qui fonctionne très bien sans lui. D’où sans doute un certain mépris dans l’Hexagone pour le terme *courriel*, mépris exprimé avec divers degrés d’impatience ou de conviction. Ce genre de débats n’existe à peu près pas au Québec.

Je rejetterais donc aussi le qualificatif *vieillot* pour la France et la Francophonie hors-Québec, parce qu’il présuppose une jeunesse plus ardente, ce qui n’est pas le cas.

Pour être méchant, on pourrait à la limite dire *mort-né*, mais bien que clairement minortiaire, il semble plutôt [en progression](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=courriel%2Cmail%2Ce-mail%2Cemail%2Ccourrier+%C3%A9lectronique&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1990&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Ccourriel%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BCourriel%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bcourriel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cmail%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bmail%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMail%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BMAIL%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ce%20-%20mail%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BE%20-%20mail%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Be%20-%20mail%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BE%20-%20Mail%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BE%20-%20MAIL%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Cemail%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BEmail%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bemail%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BEMAIL%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BeMail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Ccourrier%20%C3%A9lectronique%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bcourrier%20%C3%A9lectronique%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BCourrier%20%C3%A9lectronique%3B%2Cc0). <sub>On remarquera aussi, quoique ce ne soit pas le sujet ici, que le faible déclin de *mail* et *e-mail* s’amorce en 2003, justement l’année de la recommandation de l’Académie.</sub>

[image]

---

#### Que faire donc ?

Concernant la messagerie électronique, il semble y avoir une situation où il faut ménager la chèvre et le chou. Proposez *mail*, ou même dans une certaine mesure *e-mail*, aux Québécois, et ils tiqueront sur le terme. Proposez *courriel* aux francophones hors-Québec, et vous avez probablement le même résultat.

Il y a diverses solutions possibles :

- Si la clientèle est très majoritairement ou à peu près exclusivement européenne, ***e-mail*** me semble convenir, et ***mail*** est sans doute assez explicite pour être bien compris. Si elle est surtout québécoise, privilégier ***courriel*** me semble plus judicieux.
- Si l’on cible les gens de part et d’autre de l’Atlantique, et s’il s’agit d’une application pour laquelle diverses langues d’installation sont disponibles, il y a toujours la possibilité d’ajuster quelques petits paramètres en fonction de la localité : *français (Belgique); français (France); français (Québec); français (Suisse), etc.*
- Si la dernière option n’est pas envisageable, il reste celle qui au final me semble personnellement la plus satisfaisante, celle déjà proposée dans [cette réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/32182/13100) : ***Mél.*** Cette abréviation de *messagerie électronique* a tous les avantages : elle est courte, elle est clairement française avec son accent aigu, et c’est un homophone (si l’on veut) de *mail*. Elle n’offusquera trop gravement ni en Europe ni en Amérique, ne se prêtera à aucune ambiguïté, et ne prendra guère de place dans un formulaire d’inscription ou autre à remplir par des utilisateurs. De plus, contrairement à *mail*, *e-mail* ou *courriel*, qui dans leur sens strict sont des termes s’appliquant aux messages plutôt qu’aux adresses, ***mél.*** est conçue pour introduire une adresse de messagerie électronique.

Answer (score 4):

Le mot `courriel` est celui [officiellement recommandé](https://www.legifrance.gouv.fr/affichTexte.do?cidTexte=JORFTEXT000000412994) et à mon avis reste quand même utilisé, par exemple par l'administration. Adresse électronique est aussi utilisé mais moins souvent.

Si l'objectif est par exemple d'être un champ dans un formulaire une option est `Mél.` qui a l'avantage, en plus de sa faible longueur, d'être très proche de `Mail`.

Answer (score 3):

Presque personne n'utilise `courriel` (du moins en France, c'est peut être différent dans les autres pays francophones, adapte toi à la cible de ton soft)

`Mail` me semble adapté, on peut aussi utiliser `Email` mais on le rencontre moins souvent.

On utilise aussi parfois `mail` pour parler de l'*adresse* mail, si tu as besoin d'un champs spécifique pour entrer une adresse mail, il est préférable d'utilier `adresse mail` pour lever toute ambiguïté

Comment: en Belgique également il me semble que l'emploi de courriel est assez confidentiel.

Comment: Ouais, personne n'utiliserait mail tout court pour autre chose que le courrier electronique, donc aucune raison d'en rajouter avec e-mail.

Answer (score 2):

J'entends souvent et j'utilise presque toujours [*courriel*](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8353974) au Québec. Parfois j'entends aussi « un message par courriel/courrier électronique », similairement à ce qu'on aurait avec l'[*adresse*](http://granddictionnaire.com/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=1299116) (courriel, de courrier électronique) et qui conserve la nuance entre le contenant son contenu et l'adéquation avec l'origine postale. Je trouve ces termes parfaitement modernes et adéquats (se rappelant que l'[*e-mail*](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/email) vaut simplement pour *electronic mail*, un composé des termes parfaitement usuels dans la langue source).

---

Plus généralement les emprunts *mail* et *e-mail* (l'emprunt intégral) sont certainement [utilisés](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=courriel%2Cmail%2Ce-mail%2Cemail%2Ccourrier%20%C3%A9lectronique&year_start=1800&year_end=2020&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccourriel%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ce%20-%20mail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cemail%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ccourrier%20%C3%A9lectronique%3B%2Cc0). Le mot *mail* pour courriel hors du contexte des coordonnées et sans marque comme l'italique devient un homonyme du mot [*mail*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/mail) en français. Par exemple, le *mail Champlain* n'est ni un courriel de Samuel de Champlain ni un prototype de courriel rédigé à la manière de ceux qu'il rédigeait, mais plutôt un centre commercial à Brossard (au Québec)...

Avec un verbe comme *envoyer* j'ai déjà aussi entendu l'emprunt *mail*, prononcé tel que le mot l'est en anglais puisque toute autre prononciation me semble faire l'objet d'une évaluation négative de ma part ; et donc je trouve que l'abréviation [*mél.*](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/2467), quoique originale, ne s'approche pas suffisamment de ma perception ni de la morphologie du mot *mail* ; autrement entre deux possibilités où l'une me demande de prononcer un mot en anglais et l'autre, de m'exprimer naturellement dans ma langue, je choisis la deuxième.